# Register a Spark UDAF in SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

There is plenty of documentation online for how to define a UDAF and register it, but I've not seen any example using SQL. For example, let's say I've defined a custom UDAF:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction    

class MyUDAF extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  ...
}
```

I understand that you can compile the jar, add it to the Spark classpath, and register and use it with the scala API:

```
$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-shell  --jars my-udaf.jar
> spark.udf.register("myUDAF", new MyUDAF)
> spark.sql("select myUDAF(column) from ...")
```

In the SQL API, there is [`CREATE FUNCTION`](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/language-manual/create-function.html), but according to the docs that expects a Hive UDF/UDAF, not a Spark one. That is, the UDAF should subclass `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.hive.UDAF`, not Spark's `UserDefinedAggregateFunction`. Indeed, if I try, then I get the following error:

```
spark-sql> CREATE FUNCTION myUDAF AS 'MyUDAF';
spark-sql> select myUDAF(column) from blah;
Error in query: No handler for Hive UDF 'MyUDAF'; line 1 pos 7
```

It seems strange that the SQL and scala API's would treat UDAF registration differently. **Is there a way to register a Spark UDAF using the SQL API?** `CREATE FUNCTION` seems not to work.

Ultimately, what I'm trying to do is register some UDAF's with a Spark thrift server and register them automatically when the server starts. There may be a different approach. For example, [this article](https://medium.com/@anicolaspp/apache-spark-as-a-distributed-sql-engine-4373e254e0f9) starts the thrift server using a Scala class instead of `start-thriftserver.sh`.

Comment: I've only been able to do this via Hiva UDF as well. I hope someone finds this question and has an answer to using Spark UDF in HiveThriftServer.